# SAS merge datasets to overwrite values

Tags: sas

I want to use dataset B to overwrite some values in dataset A by merging dataset A & B with a merging ID. However it doesn't work as expected. Here is the test I did:

```
/* create table A */
data a;
  infile datalines;
  input id1 $ id2 $ var1;
datalines;
    1 a 10
    1 b 10
    2 a 10
    2 b 10
;
run;

/* create table B */
data b;
  infile datalines;
  input id1 $ var1 var2;
datalines;
    1 20 30
    2 20 30
;
run; 

/* merge A&B to overwrite var1 in table A using values in table B */
data c;
    merge a b;
    by id1;
run;
```

Table C looks like this:

```
 ID1 ID2 VAR1 VAR2

 1   a     20   30

 1   b     10   30

 2   a     20   30

 2   b     10   30
```

Why the 10s in row 2&4 didn't get replaced by 20 from table B? While var2 works as expected?

I know I can do this simply using proc SQL, and that's what I did to solve the problem. But I still quite curious if there is a way to do what I wanted using merge? And why this wasn't working? I prefer merge over SQL in this circumstance because the logic is easier to implement (util I found this not working properly).

I use SAS 9.4.

Comment: You have duplicate values by `id1` in table A. I think there's no simpe approach by using any merge/update/modify to achieve this.

Comment: Don't use code snippets with anything other than the languages they explicitly work with (mostly, html/javascript/etc.).

Comment: Also relevant (but not an exact dup), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25251177/when-using-multiple-datasets-in-a-set-or-a-merge-with-duplicate-by-values-why-d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `merge` method could still work fine, you would just need to be more explicit about how to choose the 'best' value for var1, such as:

```
data c (drop = a_var1 b_var1);
    merge a(rename=(var1 = a_var1))
          b(rename=(var1 = b_var1));
    by id1;
    * Now you have two different variables named a_var1 and b_var1;
    * Implement logic to choose your favorite;
    if NOT MISSING(b_var1) Then DO;
        var1 = b_var1;
        var1_source='B';
    END;
    else DO;
        var1 = a_var1;
        var1_source='A';
    END;
run;
```

If your criteria for which 'var1' to choose is as simple as 'If b exists, use it' then this is identical to the the SQL method with `coalesce()`.

Where I've found this method useful is for more complicated criteria, plus its always nice to know the source of the data (which doesn't happen with `coalesce()`).

Answer (score 2):

This has to do with how SAS iterates over the data sets during the merge.  Basically, the second record for each of A doesn't get lined up with a record from B.  The value of VAR2 is carried over from the previous record.  VAR1 gets its value from A (because there is no B).

**IF** there is record in B for **EVERY** ID1, then you can rewrite your merge like this to achieve what you want.

```
/* merge A&B to overwrite var1 in table A using values in table B */
data c;
    merge a(drop=var1) b;
    by id1;
run;
```

This drops the VAR1 from A so that it is carried down from the record in B.

Otherwise you will need more complex logic (might I suggest an SQL left join with the `coalesce()` function?).

Answer (score 2):

Like DomPazz suggests, `proc sql` is the way to do this. `merge` will only keep one value from each data set. The `coalesce` function pick the first non-missing value from the list, so it uses `var1` from `b`, but if `b.var1` is null then it uses `a.var1`.

```
proc sql;
create table c as
select
  a.id1,
  a.id2,
  coalesce(b.var1,a.var1) as var1,
  b.var2
from
  a
  left join b
  on a.id1 = b.id1
;
quit;
```